# Observation (not a question): the commands \guillemotleft and \guillemotright appear to be misspellings

Tags: punctuation

The traditional French double quotation marks, « and », are called *guillemets*. They are used in the scripts of many modern languages, including some forms of Chinese (as 《 and 》 in restricted contexts).

The standard LaTeX commands to produce them, however, are `\guillemotleft` and `\guillemotright`; substituting `e` for the `o` leads to a compiler error. It seems that a non-standard spelling of *guillemet* influence the choice of the LaTeX command.

My *Petit Robert* (vintage 1991) defines *guillemot*: "Oiseau palmipède voisin du pingouin, habitant les régions arctiques [Web-footed bird related to the penguin, inhabiting arctic regions]". Perhaps this is all a plot to plant Linux imagery in people's LaTeX code.

Comment: It seems that Adobe has acknowledged the error, but they think it's too late to change the characters' names in their tables.

Comment: Not sure they can really be removed, but adding the correct spelling might be useful.